# Why isn't my first ever PHP class working as expected?

Tags: php, mysql, class

I am writing my first ever PHP class, trying to learn OO concepts as I go along. The goal of this code is to record a user's IP and related parameters into a database that I might later use as the basis for applying a temporary ban. (No let's not discuss the merits of that strategy - let's keep to coding classes please!). Here's what I have:

```
class banAss {

    public function __construct(mysqli $db){
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->visitip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $this->visitAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $this->visitDate = time();
    }

    public function addBan(){
        $sql = "Insert into banned (visitIP, visitAgent, visitDate,) values (?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->db, $sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssi", $this->visitip, $this->visitAgent, $this->visitDate);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

}

$banned = new banAss($db);
$banned->addBan();
```

It's worth noting that I do have a valid database connection that has been opened using mysqli. I have been playing whackamole with the error messages on this. Currently they stand at:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/c9/public_html/admin/login.php on line 16

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/c9/public_html/admin/login.php on line 17

Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/c9/public_html/admin/login.php on line 18
```

I don't understand these messages. They suggest perhaps that the 'mysqli_prepare' line that created the variable $stmt messed up somehow, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in...

Read closely: it's telling you you're passing in a boolean value when the function doesn't expect it there. [`mysqli_prepare()`](https://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) returns a boolean `FALSE` when it encounters an error, and that's what you're attempting to pass into the `mpsqli_stmt_bind_param()` function, thereby having *it* produce an error and a boolean `FALSE` value, which just trickles down.

Use [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_error) to get the exact error you're getting and possibly a little insight into how to fix said error.

Comment: Thank you! I did as you suggested and it was a simple syntax error in the sql (trailing comma after the last parameter visitDate). I think learning a new technology primed me to look for the most mysterious causes first, rather than the most trivial. Thank you for helping me see what was right in front of me.

Answer (score 2):

Your query has a syntax error, which means all of the prepare and subsequent calls fail:

```
$sql = "Insert into banned (visitIP, visitAgent, visitDate,) etc...
                                                          ^---dangling comma
```

Never ever assume that a DB operation has succeeded. You need to check for failure, which in your case is a returned value of boolean FALSE:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare(....);
if ($stmt === false) {
       ... oops something blew up
}
```

Comment: What does your construction with the three equal signs mean?